# How can I find percent complete in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

I can't seem to find an elegant way of doing this.

But let's say my model `Projects` has many `Tasks`.

Each `task` has a boolean field for `complete`.

So if I have 10 `tasks` and 4 are "complete" and 6 are not, then I am only 40% complete.

Is there a slick way of doing this in a `scope` so that the SQL is lean?

I already have two scopes like:

```
  scope :complete, lambda {
    where("tasks.complete = true")
  }

  scope :not_complete, lambda {
    where("tasks.complete = false")
  }
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that since you're looking to get a final value out of this a model method would be the best approach. (scopes should return a Relation in order to support chaining) You could use these scopes to return the percent complete, something along the lines of:

```
def percent_complete
  not_complete.size.to_f / complete.size.to_f
end
```

Or if you require big_decimal and big_decimail/util in your model you could use to_d to get decimal division. Then in your view all you have to do is @project.percent_complete

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the chaining and Relation.  I changed it to:     def self.percent_complete
    c = complete.size.to_f
    n = not_complete.size.to_f
    return 0 if c == 0
    return 100 if n == 0
    not_complete.size.to_f / complete.size.to_f    
  end